# Mal uso del confirm() con PHP y Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, checkbox

Tengo una **tabla** con datos ordenados en filas y columnas. Una columna es para **eliminar**, mediante **checkboxs** seleccionados, cuando pulsemos el botón de **ELIMINAR** y se nos abra un "**confirm()**" para confirmar la eliminación o ser cancelada.

En la segunda cuestión tengo el **problema: en la cancelación.** Si pulso cancelar, no se me borran o se desactivan los checkboxs... ¡No lo logro conseguir!

**Código HTML/PHP:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Panel del administrador</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/desmarcar_checkboxs.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="tabla_datos_cabana" id="tabla_datos_cabana" method="POST">
            <div id="mostrar_cabanas">
                <table class="table table-striped" id="tabla" name="tabla" width="600" border="2" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: 10pt">
                    <center>
                        <tr>
                            <thead style="background-color:#A9F5A9">
                                <td width=\"150\">
                                    <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Eliminar</center></b></font>
                                </td>
                            </thead>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        $datos = BD::obtenerCabanas();
                        foreach($datos as $cabana){
                            echo "<tr>";
                               echo "<td width=\"150\"><center><input type='checkbox' name='marcados[]' id='marcados[]' value=".$cabana->getIdcabana()."></center>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </center>
                </table>


                <!-- Botón ELIMINAR cabaña/s -->
                <div class="boton_eliminar" class="table-responsive" align="left">
                    <font face="verdana">
                        <b><input type="submit" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="eliminar_cabanas" id="eliminar_cabanas" onclick="return confirm('¿Deseas realmente eliminar estas cabañas?');" value="Eliminar cabañas" /></b>
                    </font>
                </div>

                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el botón "Eliminar cabañas"...
                if(isset($_POST['eliminar_cabanas'])){
                    if(empty($_POST['marcados'])){
                        echo "<h4><center>No se ha seleccionado ninguna cabaña.</center></h4>";
                    }else{
                        foreach($_POST['marcados'] as $valor){
                            //Nos conectamos a la base de datos.
                            $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "osmarrural");
                            //Realizamos la consulta.
                            $sql = sprintf("DELETE FROM cabanas WHERE idcabana='%d'", $valor);
                            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
                        }
                        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; URL=menu_administrador.php\">";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código de la llamada del fichero **desmarcar_checkboxs.js:**

```
//Seleccionamos el botón.
var btn = document.getElementById('eliminar_cabanas');
//Asignamos el evento click.
btn.onclick = function(e){
    //Obtenemos y asignamos el valor de retorno de confirm: true o false.
    let option =confirm('¿Deseas realmente eliminar estas cabañas?');
    if(!option){ //Si es falso...
        //Seleccionamos todos los checks.
        let checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
        //Iteramos sobre estos.
        checks.forEach(function(el){
            //Asigamos el atributo a false.
            el.checked = false; 
        });
    }
}
```

Si me meto al inspector con F12, me sale el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at desmarcar_checkboxs.js:5
```

**Imagen del error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que te está pasando es que no está encontrando el botón (`btn` es `null`). ¿Dónde estás ejecutando el código? ¿Puede ser que lo estés ejecutando antes de que se hayan creado los elementos HTML?

Comment: Estoy ejecutando el evento desde JS. Tengo cargado en el head el fichero .js donde se carga la función.

Comment: Ahí es donde está el problema. Modifico mi respuesta para incluirlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo algunos problemas como que:

Defines el `onclick` directamente en el HTML y luego en el código

No cierras los elementos `td` al crear los checks

Todos los checks tienen los mismos ids y éstos incluyen corchetes.

No anulas el envío del formulario en caso de que el usuario cancele la operación. En este caso la función debería devolver `false` para anular la ejecución.

El error que te da indica que el método `getElementById` no ha devuelto ningún resultado y por lo tanto `btn` es `null`. Esto es debido a que, como comentas, tienes tu código js en el `head` de la página.

El navegador ejecuta el código javascript de la página mientras está interpretando el código HTML. Es decir, si el código está antes del `body` se ejecutará antes de que se creen los elementos de la página, si el código está al final (después del `body` los elementos ya estarán creados). Evidentemente si el código se encuentra en mitad de la página, a parte de ser más confuso, en el momento de ejecutarse existirán unos elementos (los definidos antes del código) y otros no.

La solución más fácil es, como he comentado, poner el código al final de la página. Otra opción sería poner el código en una función y asociarla al [evento `DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) del objeto `document`.

```js
//Seleccionamos el botón.
var btn = document.getElementById('eliminar_cabanas');
//Asignamos el evento click.
btn.onclick = function(e){
    //Obtenemos y asignamos el valor de retorno de confirm: true o false.
    let option =confirm('¿Deseas realmente eliminar estas cabañas?');
    if(!option){ //Si es falso...
        //Seleccionamos todos los checks.
        let checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
        //Iteramos sobre estos.
        checks.forEach(function(el){
            //Asigamos el atributo a false.
            el.checked = false; 
        });
    }
    return option;
}
```

```html
<form action="" name="tabla_datos_cabana" id="tabla_datos_cabana" method="POST">
    <div id="mostrar_cabanas">
        <table class="table table-striped" id="tabla" name="tabla" width="600" border="2" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" style="font-size: 10pt">
            <center>
                <tr>
                    <thead style="background-color:#A9F5A9">
                        <td width="150">
                            <font face="verdana" color="blue"><b><center>Eliminar</center></b></font>
                        </td>
                    </thead>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="150"><center><input type='checkbox' name='marcados[]' id='marcados[]' value="cab1"></center></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="150"><center><input type='checkbox' name='marcados[]' id='marcados[]' value="cab2"></center></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="150"><center><input type='checkbox' name='marcados[]' id='marcados[]' value="cab3"></center></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="150"><center><input type='checkbox' name='marcados[]' id='marcados[]' value="cab4"></center></td>
                </tr>
            </center>
        </table>

        <!-- Botón ELIMINAR cabaña/s -->
        <div class="boton_eliminar" class="table-responsive" align="left">
            <font face="verdana">
                <b><input type="submit" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="eliminar_cabanas" id="eliminar_cabanas" value="Eliminar cabañas" /></b>
            </font>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál sería la solución? Me sigue dando el error que puse en la pregunta: en la línea 4, línea equivalente a la creación del evento "onclick", ya eliminé el evento onclick del HTML.

Comment: Abre el código con las "herramientas de desarrollo" del navegador y comprueba que el código en el que te da error. Si, como en el código que muestras, estás asignando una función no debería darte este error.

Comment: Añado imagen de "herramientas de desarrollo" del error.

Comment: ¿pero al ser código JS tendré que llamar al archivo desde head en la cabecera, no?

Comment: No. Si el código lo tienes en un fichero js y lo incluyes con un tag `<script src="....` también puedes ponerlo al final del `body`